# How to convert .Rdata format into text file format

Tags: r, export-to-csv, file-conversion

I am a novice in R and I am trying to convert .Rdata format file into  comma delimited text file format. Can someone help me out regarding this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
load("yourData.RData")
ls() #returns a list of all the objects you just loaded (and anything else in your environment)
write.csv(theItemOfInterestFromYourDRadataFileAsThereMayBeMoreThanOneThingInthere,
  file="yourCSV.csv")
```

Comment: `write.csv` will have to use the name of the variable that you want to write to csv in the call. It may not necessarily be "yourData"

Comment: Hey its writing only one record into the csv file.Just the name of the data set.

Comment: @SOaddict; what does `str(yourData)` return?

Answer (score 10):

An `.RData` file can contain more than 1 object of any class.

If your file contains more than 1 object of `data.frame`-like class, then the following should work

```
resave <- function(file){
  e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  load(file, envir = e)
  objs <- ls(envir = e, all.names = TRUE)
  for(obj in objs) {
    .x <- get(obj, envir =e)
    message(sprintf('Saving %s as %s.csv', obj,obj) )
    write.csv(.x, file = paste0(obj, '.csv'))
  }
}

  resave('yourData.RData')
```

You can change the call to `write.csv` to do what you want. If your  objects won't behave nicely with `write.csv`, then you shouldn't be trying this.

Comment: I'm getting this error:  `Error in data.frame(`2` = list(pos = c(6506L, 6601L, 21801L, 21811L, 21902L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7670, 9729, 114, 2422
Calls: resave ... as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.list -> eval -> eval -> data.frame`

Comment: I asked here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413728/converting-rdata-files-to-csv-error-in-data-frame-arguments-imply-differing-nu