# R: rbind a list of data.frames with different columns in different data frames

Tags: r, lapply, rbind

I've a list of 11,383 data frames. I need to merge them into one big data frame, but the have different columns (2,3,4 columns) so when i use rbind_all from Dplyr i get not desired result.

One way around would be to rbind data frames that have the same number of columns (the have different headers, but i don't mind about them). As i have data frames with 2,3 and 4 columns, it would result in 3 big data frames according to the number of columns of every single data frame in the list.

Expected Output:

Data frame with 4 columns:

```
SKU             Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2003091070002P  Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2.00E+12        Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2003120060008P  Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2004121460080P  Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
2.00G+12        Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
2004121440802P  Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
2.00A+12        Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
```

Data frame with 2 columns:

```
            SKU         PROMOCIONES
1   110 2089060010006P  PROMOCIONES
2   111 2089660010006P  PROMOCIONES
```

#

This is my code:

```
df_2col <- data.frame()  #Starts Data frame for dfs with 2 columns

df_3col <- data.frame()  #Starts Data frame for dfs with 3 columns

df_4col <- data.frame()  #Starts Data frame for dfs with 4 columns


lapply(my_list, function(i){
    if (ncol(i) == 2)
        df_2col <- rbind(i)
    ifelse (ncol(i) == 3)
        df_3col <- rbind(i)
    ifelse (ncol(i) == 4)
        df_4col <- rbind(i)
})
```

But i get this error:

```
Error in ifelse(ncol(i) == 3) : argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

A list example of my data:

```
list(list(structure(list(SKU = "2079230130006P", Decohogar = "Decohogar", 
    Para.la.Mesa = "Para.la.Mesa", Copas.y.Vasos = "Copas.y.Vasos"), .Names = c("SKU", 
"Decohogar", "Para.la.Mesa", "Copas.y.Vasos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 134L)), 
    list(structure(list(SKU = "2079240080001P", Decohogar = "Decohogar", 
        Para.la.Mesa = "Para.la.Mesa", Copas.y.Vasos = "Copas.y.Vasos"), .Names = c("SKU", 
    "Decohogar", "Para.la.Mesa", "Copas.y.Vasos"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 132L)), 
    list(structure(list(SKU = "2069060020005P", PROMOCIONES = "PROMOCIONES"), .Names = c("SKU", 
    "PROMOCIONES"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 111L)), 
    list(structure(list(SKU = "2047121452095P", Dormitorio = "Dormitorio", 
        Colchones = "Colchones", X2.plazas = "X2.plazas"), .Names = c("SKU", 
    "Dormitorio", "Colchones", "X2.plazas"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 223L)), 
    list(structure(list(SKU = "2069060010006P", PROMOCIONES = "PROMOCIONES"), .Names = c("SKU", 
    "PROMOCIONES"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 110L)), 
    list(structure(list(SKU = "2069060010006P", PROMOCIONES = "PROMOCIONES"), .Names = c("SKU", 
    "PROMOCIONES"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 109L)))
```

NOTE: This would work when you know the number of columns for every single data frame in the list. Is there a way of doing this dinamycaly? I mean, if in the future, there is a data frame with 5 columns, the code should return also a big data frame with 5 columns for this data frames.

Comment: Do they have intersecting column names?

Comment: @akrun, Yes, the have a commun column: "SKU", its the first column in every single data frame. I've put some data, so you can see how it is. Thanks.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);rbindlist(do.call(`c`, my_list), fill=TRUE)`

Comment: Or maybe merge them? `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), my_list)`

Comment: @akrun, With data.table got: `Error in rbindlist(do.call(c, my_list), fill = TRUE) : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list`

Comment: Based on the dput showed, I am getting `8` columns with no error message. I am using `data.table_1.9.5`

Comment: @OmarGonzales I posted the output as an answer.  Did you get the error message on the dput dataset or on something else?

Comment: @akrun, that is not what i'm lookin for. I don't want any NAs values, i think this happens cause the dataframes have different columns. This is way i think, it's better to separate them in new data frames according their ncol(). See my code, for the if else part.

Comment: Oh Ok, Can you post the expected output also based on the my_list.  I was looking at docendodiscimus code also which gave the same result.  Sorry.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Based on your code, it is rbinding all those list elements with `3` columns, also with 4 columns separately without checking the column names.  Here, in your `my_list`, there are instances where the 4 column elements have different column names.  What should we do iin that case?

Comment: I don't mind about the columns names. As you see, the col names are the same in the rows. I just need to combine them, and maybe use random colnames. I put some desired output, that i hope will make my point clearer.

Comment: Here is what I find confusing `SKU Decohogar Para.la.Mesa Copas.y.Vasos` and `SKU Dormitorio Colchones X2.plazas`  Ok, I got it. it is not relevant..

Comment: Why would you want to merge all data.frames in a big data.frame, when they have a different number of columns? You should merge them into a list. My 2 cents

Comment: @akrun, think of it as 4 columns: SKU, Category, SubCat, Product. So, in Cat you would have: "Decohogar", and "Dormitorio". In SubCat, "Para.la.Mesa" and "Colchones", and in "Product", "Copas.y.Vasos", and "X2.plazas".  Thanks.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I updated the solution. please check if that helps

Comment: @naltipar, i don't want to do that, read the tittle of the question: in different data frames, according to the number of columns of every single data frame within the list.

Comment: @OmarGonzales can you provide the example that reproduce the error?

Comment: @akrun, this is the error when i run your code: `Error in split.default(my_list1, indx) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0` . don't know which exact part is causing it.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I was able to replicate the error by inserting a NA list element.  Updated the solution, please check if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could flatten the list elements `do.call(`c`,..)` get the number of columns (`ncol`) for each list element ("indx"), use this to `split` the list, `rbindlist` the resulting elements.

```
library(data.table)
my_list1 <- do.call(`c`, my_list)
indx <- sapply(my_list1, ncol)
lst <- lapply(split(my_list1, indx), rbindlist)
lst
#$`2`
#              SKU PROMOCIONES
#1: 2069060020005P PROMOCIONES
#2: 2069060010006P PROMOCIONES
#3: 2069060010006P PROMOCIONES

#$`4`
#             SKU  Decohogar Para.la.Mesa Copas.y.Vasos
#1: 2089230130006P  Decohogar Para.la.Mesa Copas.y.Vasos
#2: 2089240080001P  Decohogar Para.la.Mesa Copas.y.Vasos
#3: 2047121452095P Dormitorio    Colchones     X2.plazas
```

If we need to get separate `data.frame` objects (not recommended), use `list2env`

```
 list2env(setNames(lst, paste0('dat',seq_along(lst))), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

#### Update

If there are NULL or NA values as one of the list elements, we could get this error

```
my_list1[[7]] <- NA
split(my_list1, sapply(my_list1, ncol))
#Error in split.default(my_list1, sapply(my_list1, ncol)) : 
 #group length is 0 but data length > 0
```

Then, we could check whether the elements are `data.frame` ("isDF"), subset the list and get the "ncol", and do as before.

```
isDF <- sapply(my_list1, is.data.frame)
indx <- sapply(my_list1[isDF], ncol)
lapply(split(my_list1[isDF], indx), rbindlist)
```

Comment: Got this: `Error in split.default(my_listfinal, indx) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0`

It works nice with the data provided, but maybe some data frame within the list is giving me trouble. Some of them have 0 rows... 

May you add some explanation for every line of the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @OmarGonzales It would be better if you can post the dput of a small example that reproduce the error as the example you showed works here.

Comment: got this error this time: `Error in args[[i]] : attempt to select less than one element`, when running this line: `lst <- lapply(split(my_list1[isDF], indx), rbindlist)`

Comment: @OmarGonzales It must be something connected with the NULL elements.  How big is your list?  Also, test this in a very small subset of your list and if the error persists, then please dput that subset

Comment: i think, i should have clear my objects (rm = list = ls()). I don't get problems with your code, but get this message:
**Error in data.frame(`2` = list(SKU = c("2003120060006P", "2003120060006P",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3939, 2563, 4786, 95```**

Comment: @OmarGonzales When do you get this error?  While writing it to file?? Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413728/converting-rdata-files-to-csv-error-in-data-frame-arguments-imply-differing-nu

Comment: yes i was using: write.csv. I've tried that link and got:  `Error in lst[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'`. Maay you update the answer, to include the method to export those data frames as CSV files?

Comment: @OmarGonzales If you want to save it as different files `lst1 <- lapply(split(my_list1[isDF], indx), rbindlist); lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) write.csv(lst1[[i]], file=paste0('file','i', '.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

rbind_all has a fill function that replaces blank data with NA.
When I tried to use rbind the first time I got an error because the data set you have provided is a list of list not a list of dataframes. I first converted the nested lists to dataframes then used rbind to create the single dataframe.

your example data is "x"

```
sapply(x, class)
x2 <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
x3 <- rbind_all(x2)
```

I don't know if you are making a tidy data frame but if you are you could use tidyr to help

```
library(tidyr)
x4 <- gather(x3, key=SKU, na.rm=TRUE)[,-2]
```

**UPDATE**

The question is solved now but here is my update to my solution to make a list of dataframes of individual catagories

```
x5 <- lapply(unique(x4$value), function(n) filter(x4, value == n))
```