# Loading an existing .RData file into an R program

Tags: r, dataframe, rdata

I have a .RData file. I want to do some operations on the dataframe that this file contains. Can I load this file on my R program and convert it into a dataframe? The only option I know currently is to convert the ..RData file to a csv and convert that csv into a data frame again. I am looking for a neater solution. I got this file from a friend of mine and I cannot produce the dataframe from scratch.

Comment: Try `?load` for help

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If yes: Just go to File -> Open File...

Comment: "convert the ..RData file to a csv" Wow. `RData` is a binary format. How do you even do this?

Comment: @RichieCotton Using this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189467/how-to-convert-rdata-format-into-text-file-format)

Comment: @Christoph Yes that does the job. Thanks.